# Facebook and twitter icons do not appear in aspx page when ran via Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, bootstrap-modal

I am using visual studio 2013 with an example made by Bootstrap v3.3.5 in aspx.

when I run the website in visual studio, the icons do not show, it looks like this:

[image: Wrong result]

When I run the website normally without visual studio, it looks like this:

[image: Correct result]

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<title>:: Contact Us | Striking Interior Design Company ::</title>
<meta name="description" content="Welcome to Striking Interior Design Template">
<meta name="keywords" content="interior, design, services, expert, analysis, structure, luxury, home, kitchen, berdroom, living room, bathroom, kid, office, infrastructure">
<meta name="author" content="Saptarang">

<!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- Google Font Code -->
<link href='../../../../../../fonts.googleapis.com/css@family=Roboto+Slab_3A400,100,300,700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,latin-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='../../../../../../fonts.googleapis.com/css@family=Open+Sans_3A400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,latin-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="~/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/prettyPhoto.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bxslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/color.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/boxed.css" />

<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="../../../../../../html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- Favicon and Apple Icons -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/images/icons/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="~/images/icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="~/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="~/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
</head>

<body id="top" onLoad="initialize()" class="inner">
<div id="preloader">
 <img src="images/Preloader.gif" alt="Preloader" />
</div>
<div class="boxed">

<!-- ::: START HEADER ::: -->
<header id="home" class="cbp-af-header header2">
  <div class="header-top BGdark">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <span><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (123) 456-7890 </span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-fax"></i> (123) 456-7890</span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> <a href="mailto:info@companynme.com" title="">info@companynme.com</a> </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <ul class="social list-inline pull-right">
          <li><a class="fb" href="#" title="Follow Us on Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="tw" href="#" title="Follow Us on Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="yt" href="#" title="Watch Our Videos"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="pt" href="#" title="Watch Our Videos"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="li" href="#" title="Follow Us on LinkedIn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="fl" href="#" title="Watch Our gallery"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="gplus" href="#" title="Google Plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="ig" href="#" title="Watch Our Gallery"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="vk" href="#" title="Follow Us on vk"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Header top end -->
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 logo">
        <a title="company Logo" href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/company.png" width="200" height="100" alt="Company Logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 cbp-af-inner rightnav">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
        
          <!-- ::: Main Nav ::: -->
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="sub"><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
               <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 ::: -->
                  <ul class="sub-nav">
                      <li><a href="index.html" title="Home Version 1">Home Version 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index2.html" title="Home Version 2">Home Version 2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index3.html" title="Home Version 3">Home Version 3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="index4.html" title="Home Version 4">Home Version 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 end::: -->
              </li>
              <li class="sub"><a href="#" title="About">About</a>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 ::: -->
                  <ul class="sub-nav">
                      <li><a href="about1.html" title="About Us">About 1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="about2.html" title="About Us">About 2</a></li>
                      <li class="sub"><a href="#" title="Team">Team</a>
                          <!-- ::: Nav Level 2 ::: -->
                          <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li><a href="team1.html" title="Team 1">Team Hover 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="team2.html" title="Team 2">Team Hover 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="team3.html" title="Team 1">Team Hover 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="team-single.html" title="John Doe">Team Single</a></li>
                          </ul>
                          <!-- ::: Nav Level 2 ::: -->
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 end::: -->
              </li>
              
              <li class="sub"><a href="#" title="Pages">Pages</a>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 ::: -->
                  <ul class="sub-nav">
                      <li class="sub"><a href="#" title="Service">Services</a>
                          <!-- ::: Nav Level 2 ::: -->
                          <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li><a href="services.html" title="Service">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services-single-1.html" title="Service Sinle Page">Services Single</a></li>
                          </ul>
                          <!-- ::: Nav Level 2 ::: -->
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="testimonials.html" title="Testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
                      <li><a href="faq.html" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
                      <li><a href="clients.html" title="Clients">Clients</a></li>
                      <li><a href="career.html" title="Career">Career</a></li>
                      <li><a href="press.html" title="Press">Press</a></li>
                      <li><a href="404.html" title="404" target="_blank">404</a></li>
                      <li><a href="sitemap.html" title="Sitemap">Sitemap</a></li>
                      <li><a href="elements.html" title="Elements">Elements</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 end::: -->
              </li>
              
              <li class="sub"><a href="#" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 ::: -->
                  <ul class="sub-nav">
                    <li><a href="portfolio-2col.html" title="Portfolio 2 Column"> Portfolio 2 Column</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio-3col.html" title="Portfolio 3 Column"> Portfolio 3 Column</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio-4col.html" title="Portfolio 4 Column"> Portfolio 4 Column</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio-full-width.html" title="Portfolio Full Width"> Portfolio Full Width</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio1.html" title="Portfolio Single 1">Portfolio Single 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio2.html" title="Portfolio Single 2">Portfolio Single 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 end::: -->
              </li>
                 
              <li class="sub"><a href="#" title="Gallery">Gallery</a>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 ::: -->
                  <ul class="sub-nav">
                    <li><a href="gallery4.html" title="Gallery 4 Column">Gallery 4 Column</a></li>    
                    <li><a href="gallery3.html" title="Gallery 3 Column">Gallery 3 Column</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery2.html" title="Gallery 2 Column">Gallery 2 Column</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery-full-width.html" title="Gallery Full Width">Gallery Full Width</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 end::: -->
              </li>
              
              <li class="sub"><a href="#" title="Blog">Blog</a>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 ::: -->
                  <ul class="sub-nav">
                    <li><a href="blog.html" title="Gallery 4 Column">Blog Main</a></li>    
                    <li><a href="blog-single.html" title="Gallery 3 Column">Single Post</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 end::: -->
              </li>
              
              <li class="active sub"><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 ::: -->
                  <ul class="sub-nav">
                    <li><a href="contact1.html" title="Contact">Contact 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact2.html" title="Contact">Contact 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- ::: Nav Level 1 end::: -->
              </li> 
              
            </ul>
            <!-- ::: Main Nav ::: -->
            
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end container -->
</header>
<!-- ::: END ::: -->

<!--  :::  BREADCRUMBS ::: -->
<section class="breadcrumbs breadcrumbs2 contact wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="0.25s" data-wow-delay="0.45s">
   <div class="contact-info BGprime page-block">
      <div class="container wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.50s" data-wow-delay="0.50s">
        <div class="office">
            <h2 class="white text-center">Login</h2>
            
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="container page-block text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.50s" data-wow-delay="0.50s">
 
</div>
<!-- ::: END ::: -->

<!--  :::  FOOTER ::: -->
<footer class="footer2 BGdark page-block-small">
  <div class="container">
  
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="0.50s" data-wow-delay="0.50s">
     <img class="img-responsive pull-left" src="images/company-grey.png" alt="" />
        <ul class="social list-inline pull-right">
          <li><a class="fb" href="#" title="Follow Us on Facebook" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="tw" href="#" title="Follow Us on Twitter" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="yt" href="#" title="Watch Our Videos" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="pt" href="#" title="Watch Our Videos" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="li" href="#" title="Follow Us on LinkedIn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="fl" href="#" title="Watch Our gallery" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="gplus" href="#" title="Google Plus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="ig" href="#" title="Watch Our Gallery" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          <li><a class="vk" href="#" title="Follow Us on vk" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a></li>
       </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      
      <hr class="light">
        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content-box wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.50s" data-wow-delay="0.50s">
      <h5>About</h5>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, rislaoreetsuscipit turpis mollis non. Lcons is molli Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis quam non tellus ultricies accumsan. Lorem Loripiscing elit. Maecenas quis quam non tellus ultricies accumsan.</p>
      <a href="about2.html" title="About Company">Read More <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
    </div><!-- end content box -->
    
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 content-box wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.50s" data-wow-delay="0.75s">
      <h5>Quick Links</h5>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="portfolio-4col.html" title="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
       <li><a href="gallery-full-width.html" title="Gallery Full Width">Gallery</a></li>
       <li><a href="blog.html" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="press.html">Press</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact2.html" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- end content box -->
    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 content-box wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.50s" data-wow-delay="1s">
      <h5>Services</h5>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="services-single-1.html" title="Commercial design">Commercial Interior Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="services-single-2.html" title="Interior design">Residential Interior Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="services-single-3.html" title="Exterior design">Exterior design</a></li>
        <li><a href="services-single-4.html" title="Renovation">Renovation</a></li>
        <li><a href="services-single-4.html" title="Maintainance">Annual Maintainance</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- end content box -->
    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 content-box wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.50s" data-wow-delay="1.25s">
      <h5>Get in touch</h5>
      <div class="office">
        <span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 123 Main Street<br>
          Your City, State Country.</span> 
        <span><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (123) 456-7890 <br>(123) 456-7890 </span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-fax"></i> (123) 456-7890</span>
        <span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> <a href="mailto:info@companynme.com" title="">info@companynme.com</a> </span>
      </div>   
    </div><!-- end content box -->
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <hr class="light">
  
   <!-- ::: START COPYRIGHT ::: -->
   <div class="copyright wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.50s" data-wow-delay="0.50s" data-wow-offset="0"> 
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p><strong>Striking</strong> &copy; 2015. All Rights Reserved.<br> Landing Page Template Designed &amp; Developed By: <a href="../../../../../../themeforest.net/user/saptarang@ref=saptarang" title="Saptarang" target="_blank"><strong>Saptarang</strong></a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-right">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a href="terms.html" title="Terms & Conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="privacy.html" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="sitemap.html" title="Sitemap">Sitemap</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div><!-- end container -->
  </div><!-- end copyright --> 

</footer>
<!-- ::: END ::: -->
</div><!-- end boxed -->
<a href="#top" class="top"><i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-lg"></i></a>

<!--START SCRIPTS -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../../https@maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script> 
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/placeholders.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/master.js"></script>
<script>

    // Google Map for single location

    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.879489, -78.876206); // Add your coordinates here
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 17,
            scrollwheel: false,
            center: myLatlng,
            disableAutoPan: true
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas1'), mapOptions);

        var contentString = '<div class="info_content">' +
          '<h5>Striking<small>Los Angeles</small></h5>'; // name and city here

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably a pathing issue.

Comment: @user2839125 I don't see any difference in the images.

Comment: After inspect element , are you getting any error? if yes then please quote here

Comment: difference in icon

Comment: @user2839125 Also can you show us the folder structure of your project, where is the project and where are the images?

Comment: @DDave I made a mistake in the edit and it wasn't picked up, I've sumbitted a new edit and the [faulty image should be this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WgBjg.png)

Comment: in the link the structure of project http://s33.postimg.org/l7b5fliwf/434.png

Comment: @Darken seems like path issue only as earlier mentioned.

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: Your images aren't showing as it can't find the directory where they are located. When you are running it without visual studio, is it the same folder structure?

When running it in visual studio, does it contain the mappings to the icons in it's resources?

Comment: I think the problem in the font-awesome       <link href="~/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> beacuse the image inside this file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<link href="~/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

try this one

```
<link href="/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<link href="../fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and also change to other bootstrap's plugins.

Comment: Bootstrap Work without visual studio but When I run it in visual the problem showed

Comment: that's cool buddy but it seems conflict in your path directory...... did you try my suggestions?

Comment: I think the problem in the font-awesome <link href="~/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> beacuse the image inside this file

Comment: so check it by removing font-awesome.min.css...... from you page... just remove the link and check...